# Can't un-select my DevExpress LookUpEdit

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a DevExpress LookUpEdit that I am using withing Visual Studio 2008 in VB.Net.

I have the LookUpEdit bound to my datasource and the value that it is displaying may be null or one of the rows in the datasource. My program displays a treelist and when a node is select the LookUpEdit is supposed to display the assigned value (could be null) and let the user reassign the value. *I do have the LookUpEdit.Properties.AllowNullInput set to True.* Right now when the program first starts if the first node in the treelist I choose has a null value the LookUpEdit displays nothing, if I change the value of the LookUpEdit the value changes in the database, if I change to a node that has a value for the LookUpEdit the value does display.

The problem is that if I switch from a node with a value to one without the LookUpEdit displays the previous value. I  have gone through the debugger and it is still going through the fetch properly.

I have tried to reset the LookUpEdit.Text, LookUpEdit.EditValue and LookUpEdit.SelectedText but nothing works. I even replicated the conditions that the LookUpEdit has when it first displays nothing (LookUpEdit.Text = "" and LookUpEdit.EditValue = " ") but it still displays the last value.

I am setting the actual value with *lueLocation.EditValue = lueLocation.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayText(valueName)*

**EDIT**

So I narrowed it down. After I set the Text and EditValue to nothing

```
lueLocation.Text = Nothing
lueLocation.EditValue = Nothing
```

The values are set. The problem is that in the act of setting the value the dropdown menu opens. So I get it to close with `lueLocation.ClosePopup()`. For some reason when it gets called it changes the `.Text` and `.EditValue` back to the previous values and thus calls the `TextChanged Event`.

No clue why but I can't keep the dropdown menu open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. As you can see in the Edit it was the `lueLocation.ClosePopup()` that actually caused it to revert back to the previous `.Text` and `.EditValue` values. I removed the `lueLocation.ClosePopup()` which then caused my interface to have the dropdowns remain open if the value was null and closed if there was an actual assigned value.

I found that if I set the `.EditValue` to `DBNull.Value` (`lueLocation.EditValue = DBNull.Value`) rather than `Nothing`, `""`, or `" "` it set the value assigned to the LookUpEdit to nothing and automatically closed the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in the UI the key combination of Ctrl-Del should clear it and set it to nothing.  Otherwise in code, you should be able to set the EditValue = Nothing and that should do it.

Here are a couple of links on the DX site:

Search:  http://search.devexpress.com/?q=clear+lookupedit&p=T4%7cP1%7c4&d=447

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q96464.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q270901.aspx

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-Del does clear it. But when I select a new node it re-fetches the data for the LookUpEdit. Then if the new value is nothing (so want to show a blank) the LookUpEdit displays the previous (old) value.

Comment: I have tried to set the EditValue to "", " ", and Nothing (I'm using VB). And none of them clear it. It just displays the previous value.

Comment: That's odd. This has worked fine for me. Have you submitted a question to support at DevExpress.  Including some code with a support request always seems to get the best most accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it and not sure why that worked and not the other values.